# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void' in angular-cli

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2 and didn't find any proper answer for similar questions posted.

I am getting Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void' in angular-cli. I tried importing subscribe from rxjs but didn't find that library.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih10f.jpg)

please help solving this issue. please find below my service and component code into which i am calling that service.

```js
// ******************************* 

// login.service.ts

// ******************************* 

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throw';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getLoginData(){
    this.http.get('./json/login.json')
      .map((result: Response) => result.json())
      .catch(this.getError);
  }

  private getError(error: Response): Observable<any>{
      console.log(error);
      return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server Issue');
  }

}

// ******************************* 

// login.component.ts

// ******************************* 


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export class LoginComponent {
usernameModel: string;
passwordModel: string;
validLogin: Boolean;
  constructor(private router: Router, private loginService: LoginService) { }

  homeNav(){
    if(this.usernameModel === 'jay' && this.passwordModel === 'Jay'){
      this.validLogin = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
    else{
      this.validLogin = false;
      console.log('Login Error');
    }

this.loginService.getLoginData()
  .subscribe(
    data => console.log(data)
  );

  }



}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are not returning the observable in your `getLoginData` function.  Add the `return` keyword and optionally add the return type to the signature:

```
getLoginData(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('./json/login.json')
      .map((result: Response) => result.json())
      .catch(this.getError);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the `http` call, and be sure to always add typehinting to have your IDE pick up on these errors beforehand

```
getLoginData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('./json/login.json')
    .map((result: Response) => result.json())
    .catch(this.getError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i found new issue as 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/throw'' .... I have check rxjs/operator folder and i din't find throw.js .... do i need to add it externally?

Comment: The right import is `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'` (so observable, not operator). But those things are unnecessary, I believe the only thing you need there is the `map` import

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular 13

## [Post.services.ts]

Simple use return on the API

postProduct  (data: any)  {

```
return this.http.post<any>(" http://localhost:3000/productList/", data)
```

}

## [Post.component.ts]

addProduct(){

```
if(this.productForm.valid){

  this.API_DailogService.postProduct(this.productForm.value)
  .subscribe({
    next:()=>{
      alert("Product added successfully!")
    },
    error: () =>{
      alert("Error while adding product!")
    }
  })

}
```

}

## [Post.component.html]

<button (click)="addProduct()">Save

Answer (score 0):

you must return something in your function to subscribe to it, in your case,your function "getLoginData()" return "void", change this:

```
  getLoginData(){
     this.http.get('./json/login.json')
     .map((result: Response) => result.json())
     .catch(this.getError);
  }
```

to this, by adding "return":

```
  getLoginData(){
      return this.http.get('./json/login.json')
        .map((result: Response) => result.json())
        .catch(this.getError);
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Some times you forgot to use " return " in

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).